# Correctly using "&&", "||", and "!=" in PHP

Tags: php

I'm not too sure about PHP but I normally took it was like math and the brackets are done before anything else.

I have this:

```
if( !strncmp($method_id,'OPTION', 6) && ( ($method_id != 'OPTION_5') || ($method_id != 'OPTION_12') ) )
    unset( $available_methods[ $method_id ] );
```

Where `$method_id` is equal to `OPTION_` 1 through to 12.

Effectively if option 5 and 12 are available unset everything except those two.

**QUESTION**
Why doesnt the above work.

---

## EDIT

So I tried simplifying it but I think I made it harder to understand.

This is a shipping loop. The available methods are `ship:REGULAR_LOCAL`, `ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL`, `ship:PLAT_LOCAL`, `ship:REGULAR_INT`, `ship:EXPRESS_INT`, `ship:PLAT_INT`, and `FREE_SHIPPING` [where `LOCAL` is within shipping country, and `INT` is international].

When an order goes over $100, `FREE_SHIPPING` automatically kicks in, but I also want to have either `ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL` or `ship:EXPRESS_INT` present depending on where the customer is from.

```
if( !strncmp($method_id,'ship:', 5) && ( ($method_id != 'ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL') || ($method_id != 'ship:EXPRESS_INT') ) )
    unset( $available_methods[ $method_id ] );
```

This should return with only `FREE_SHIPPING`, and either `ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL` **or** `ship:EXPRESS_INT`.

**LOOP**

```
if( isset( $available_methods['FREE_SHIPPING'] ) ) {
    foreach( $available_methods as $method_id => $method ) {
        if( !strncmp( $method_id, 'ship:', 5 ) && ( ($method_id != 'ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL') && ($method_id != 'ship:EXPRESS_INT') ) )
            unset( $available_methods[ $method_id ] );
    }
}   
return $available_methods;
```

Comment: Specify your question please.

Comment: You may need to check the PHP Precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Yes, @fedorqui I think it might be a syntax error.

Comment: Please clearly list your logic and re-implement it with Brackets

Comment: Is this run inside a loop? Also, explain why above doesn't work.

Comment: Consider `in_array()` for reducing the comparisons.

Comment: Show a bit of the surrounding code; is it a loop? If so, include the relevant parts of that.

Comment: The added logic should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated question should contain the correct code already; this is how I would have written it:

```
$localOrInt = array('ship:EXPRESS_LOCAL', 'ship:EXPRESS_INT');

if (isset($available_methods['FREE_SHIPPING'])) {
    foreach ($available_methods as $method_id => $method) {
        if (!strncmp($method_id, 'ship:', 5) && !in_array($method_id, $localOrInt)) {
            unset($available_methods[$method_id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I tried this before, when Mario suggested it but I had the in_array variables back to front!

Answer (score 4):

You have some logic nonsense. Look at the or in the second part. If method_id is not 5 or method_id is not 12. Well, if it is anything but 5 or 12, you get a true out of that. If it is 5, you get "false or true" which is true. If it is 12, you get "true or false" which is true. So, the entire second half is always true. Perhaps you meant && instead of || or you want == instead of !=.

Comment: I need the || since both options 5 and 12 arent always available together. So effectively, unset all OPTION methods, but keep 5 and 12 if they are in the loop.

Comment: You are only checking one value of $method_id at a time. You are not checking a set of values since I seriously doubt you have PHP running on a cell processor with array memory. So, one single value of $method_id cannot have two values (again, I seriously doubt you are using a quantum computer). It is simply not possible for $method_id to have both value 5 and 12. It looks like you want to say "If it is an OPTION and it is not OPTION_5 and it is not OPTION_12" unset it.

Answer (score 1):

It is normally good to format the code to see it more clearly.

From:

```
if( !strncmp($method_id,'OPTION', 6) && ( ($method_id != 'OPTION_5') || ($method_id != 'OPTION_12') ) )
```

to:

```
if(

  !strncmp($method_id,'OPTION', 6)

  &&

  ( 
      ($method_id != 'OPTION_5')
      ||
      ($method_id != 'OPTION_12') 
  ) 

)
```

This part is always true:

```
  ($method_id != 'OPTION_5')
  ||
  ($method_id != 'OPTION_12')
```

Because one of those will always be true, and `true || false === false || true === true`.

So the `if` will be true iff `!strncmp($method_id,'OPTION', 6) === true`, meaning `strncmp($method_id,'OPTION', 6)===false`.

Check the logic you want to use for it.